# Oracle lock between two connection

Tags: c#, oracle, concurrency

Is it possible to lock data row between two oracle connections like this pseudo code :

First method request a row and a cursor to lock the row

```cs
private CursorVariable formCursor;
private object model;

public object Edit()
{
    using (OracleConnection connection = new OracleConnection(connectionString))
    using (OracleCommand command = connection.CreateCommand())
    {
          // Execute query like "CURSOR cursor_name IS SELECT * FROM tableOne WHERE Id = 1 FOR UPDATE"
          // Get cursor from database and set formCursor with it
          // Set model with result of select 
    }
}
```

Second method update row with modifications made on the UI, it uses cursor to unlock data row

```
public bool SaveEdit(object modifications)
{
    using (OracleConnection connection = new OracleConnection(connectionString))
    using (OracleCommand command = connection.CreateCommand())
    {
          // update model with modifications
          // Execute a query like "UPDATE table_name SET [col1 = modifications.col1, col2 = modifications.col2,...] WHERE Id = 1 CURRENT OF cursor_name"
    }
}
```

If edition is canceled the lock is released

```
public void CancelEdit()
{
    using (OracleConnection connection = new OracleConnection(connectionString))
    using (OracleCommand command = connection.CreateCommand())
    {
          // Release lock
    }         
}
```

Comment: The connection(session) locking the row must be the one to update it, if that was your question.

Comment: Yes, I'm looking for a way to achieve locking in a session a unlock in another. If this isn't possible with "FOR UPDATE" can I do it another way ?

Comment: Is it possible to run `Edit`, `CancelEdit`, `SaveEdit` within the same context/scope, as in they somehow share the same connection variable `OracleConnection connection`?

Comment: Yes, I can open a connection in Edit and Close it at the end of CancelEdit and SaveEdit